# How to find complex eigenvectors from complex eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix that represents a $2 \times 2$ linear system and I am supposed to solve to find what $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are.

$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 5 \\
   -1 & -3 \\
  \end{array} } \right] $

I got that my eigenvalues were $-1+i$ and $-1-i$. But how do I use these to find my eigenvectors?

Comment: The same way you usually do. Complex numbers aren't _that_ different from real numbers, after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **definition** of "eigenvalue" and "eigenvector".  If $-1+ i$ is an eigenvalue then there exists a vector, $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$, such that $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 5 \\ -1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}(-1+ i)x \\ (-1+ i)y\end{bmatrix}$.  Solve for $x$ and $y$.  Of course, since the set of eigenvectors corresponding to a given eigenvalue form a subspace, there will be an infinite number of possible $(x, y)$ values.

Answer (score 6):

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1-(-1+i) & 5 \\
   -1 & -3-(-1+i) \\
  \end{array} } \right] =  $$

$$ \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2-i & 5 \\
   -1 & -2-i \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

One eigenvector is $$ \begin{pmatrix} 2+i\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

and the other one is  $$ \begin{pmatrix} 2-i\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$