# Are “multiples” of complex eigenvectors also eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It is said that if we multiply a real eigenvector by any real number k and hence we get another vector lying on the same line, the new one is also an eigenvector.

Let us consider now for example a rotation matrix, whose complex eigenvectors are (1,i) and (1,-i). The eigenvalue associated to the first one is $e^{i\theta}$. We can now consider multiplying by this eigenvalue but with any possible value for the angle $\theta$ or any possible value for a pre-factor $r$ indicating magnitude. Would the resulting vectors be also complex eigenvectors? Can you say that this way you “span” the whole complex plane in the relevant direction, here the positive or counterclockwise direction?

Comment: We can multiple any eigenvector by any complex number $c$ other than $0$, and it will still be an eigenvector. If $Av=\lambda v$ then $A(cv)=\lambda (cv)$ since $A$ is linear.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2777805/471884).

Comment: Thanks to both! I have read now about the concept of “eigenspace” = subspace spanned by the eigenvector with its “multiples”, which would be an eigenline in the real context, here an eigenplane, but only in one (rotational) direction, right? Elaborating on this, the two complex eigenspaces (clockwise and counterclockwise) look to me like the two axes of a coordinate system, but sort of **polar axes**. Would this understanding be correct?